# Why set the carry flag?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I write a simple assembly function sum64, which add ecx:ebx+edx:eax, its works correct with positive number, but not in negative.

```
sum64:
add ebx,eax
adc ecx,edx
ret
```

Example:

```
edx = 1d1h
eax = a94a2003
ebx = FFFFFFFF
ecx = 00000000
```

The correct result is 1D1A94A2002h but my function return ecx:1d2h ebx:a94a2002, it is incorrect because the first "add" set the carry, why?
How to solve this?

Thanks the answers.

Comment: What negative number? Neither of the input `ecx:ebx`, nor `edx:eax` are negative interpreted as a two's complement 64-bit number split across two registers. Did you mean to test `FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFF` instead of `00000000:FFFFFFFF`?

Comment: it's correct, i forget, thanks the solution

Comment: In general addition and subtraction are not affected by the twos complement sign of the number, the logic doesnt know or care.  multiply and divide do care, not add and subtract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers you are testing are:

```
00000000ffffffff (ecx:ebx)
000001d1a94a2003 (edx:eax) +
----------------
000001d2a94a2002
```

Neither are negative (in 64-bit two's complement representation) so sum to the result that you are getting. `-1` as a 64-bit negative number would be `ffffffff` in both `ecx` and `ebx` which would give the result that you were originally expecting.

```
ffffffffffffffff (ecx:ebx)
000001d1a94a2003 (edx:eax) +
----------------
000001d1a94a2002
```

Answer (score 2):

You are still adding positive numbers because ecx:ebx (00000000FFFFFFFF) is a positive number. You need to sign-extend the high dword for this to work. If you use edx:eax for one number, you can use the **cdq** instruction for this.

Comment: it's also working, thanks. i never heard this instruction, very useful